# jQuery plugin class type name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have searched but have not been able to find any information. I know this isn't typical of jQuery however I need to appease our structure that we have for PHP and make that into the jQuery plugin per my boss.

Is there any way to extend the $.fn to add another name? For example

```
$.MyTools.useTool('piece of wood','cut');
```

or

```
$('#wood').MyTools.useTool('cut');
```

I guess MyTools would be the class and useTool would be the function. However I have done this in a plugin. We are wanting to have our plugin called MyTools and whenever you use a function in it you need to call MyTools.

Would it be better to do away with the plugin and just create a class?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean. Have you read the [article at the official jQuery Docs on creating plugins for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)? Did you use that technique? Or are you asking on alternative techniques?

Comment: @sirhc yes, I am trying something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that is no way to do this, so I had to take a different approach and take the official plugin way method by doing $.GLCFormattingCurrency('remove', data);

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, when I want to make a namespace (sort of) like that I do this for all my plugins:

```
(function( $ ){
    if(!$.fn.MyTools) {
        $.fn.MyTools = {};
    }
    $.fn.MyTools.useTool = function() {

        // do stuff

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: inside my function I have return this.each( ... ); when I do it this way I can nolonger use this inside the function

Comment: I don't understand.  Inside the this.each(...); you should be able to use 'this' to reference the current element the function is acting on.

Comment: Check out my code http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/2HsSV/ if I remove the GLCCurrencyFormatting it works fine but with it I get a this.each undefined.

Comment: GLCCurrencyFormatting? I do not see that anywhere.

Comment: Ahh, I know what your problem is.  The return this.each is only used when you use $.fn.newFunc = function() and call it like $('.className').  I see sometimes you add methods by doing $.newFunc = function() which cannot do a return this.each since this is not a jQuery object.

Comment: the $.newFunc calls go to the jQuery.newFunc function and the $('.class').newFunc goes to $.fn.newFunc

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong with this answer.  I do not know how to effectively do this.  The only good solution is under the Namespacing section of http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.